# Pass/Override Terraform object variable via command line

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I have a Terraform configuration (v0.14, AWS provider 3.32.0) in which I have defined the parameters for certain resource types as objects (input variables). Here is an (simplified) example:

```
variable "docker_config" {
  type = object({
    internal = number
    external = number
    protocol = string
  })
  default =
    {
      internal = 8300
      external = 8300
      protocol = "tcp"
    }
}
```

However, I would like to be able to override individual values via command line or environment variable.
Can I overwrite individual values of the object without having to pass the whole object? So, use default values and override them as needed:

e. g.
`TF_VAR_docker_config.internal = 1234`

or
`TF_VAR_docker_config = "{internal = 1234}"`

And this would result in:

```
    {
      internal = 1234
      external = 8300
      protocol = "tcp"
    }
```

My tests did not work. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, you can't do this directly. In near future [optional](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/type-constraints.html#experimental-optional-object-type-attributes) should be added to `object` which will simplify this.

For now, a non-perfect **workaround** could be to use [merge](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/merge.html) with regular `map`:

```
variable "docker_config_default" {
  type = object({
    internal = number
    external = number
    protocol = string
  })
  
  default = {
      internal = 8300
      external = 8300
      protocol = "tcp"
    }
}

variable "docker_config" {
  type = map
  
  validation {
    # condition is not perfect and suited only for one 
    # attribute overwrite
    condition     = (can(var.docker_config["internal"]) 
                    || can(var.docker_config["external"]) 
                    || can(var.docker_config["protocol"]))
    error_message = "Must have internal, external or protocol."
  } 
}

locals {
  docker_config = merge(var.docker_config_default, var.docker_config)
}

output "test" {
  value = local.docker_config
}
```

And you just use `local.docker_config` in your code.

Comment: Too bad. I wanted this to allow configuration of resources (RDS, ECS, etc.) without having to maintain a high number of separate variables (one variable per parameter). However, if I need an additional default-objects and a merge for each object this is not a simplification of the code. But thanks anyway, interesting idea that I can definitely use sometime. :)

Comment: @Stefan `optional` keyword for `object` will simply this, but you still will need to `merge`.